# String output to display message to user

Tags: java, string, user-interface, boolean, biginteger

When using my code I am receiving an output message stating that each number that I have entered is prime, even if it is not a prime number. How can I change my output message to reflect the correct is or is not prime result? Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
//prompt user to input a number

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "); 
// change string to int
    int number = Integer.parseInt(input); 

//display message to user of their results
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger(input); 

    String output = number + " is" + (BigInteger(input) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime     number: " + BigInteger(input);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, output);
```

}

```
public static Boolean IsPrime(BigInteger num) {
// check if number is a multiple of 2
if (num.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
  return false;
}// if not, then just check the odds
for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(num) <= 0; i =
    i.add(new BigInteger("2"))) {
  if (num.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {

   return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having an issue here -

```
String output = number + " is" 
    + (BigInteger(input) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime     number: " 
    + BigInteger(input);
```

And you want something more like this -

```
String output = num + " is" 
    + (IsPrime(num) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number.";
```

I tested your `IsPrime` function, and it correctly identified 5 as prime and 4 as not prime. You should probably rename it `isPrime` to be inline with Java naming conventions.

**EDIT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // prompt user to input a number

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number ");
    // change string to int
    int number = Integer.parseInt(input);

    // display message to user of their results
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger(input);

    String output = num + " is" + (IsPrime(num) ? " " : " not ")
            + "a prime number.";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}
```

[image: First prompt]

[image: Not Prime]

[image: Is Prime]

Comment: @elliotfrisch I changed my code to reflect what you gave me and the program is terminating after the number is inputted without giving me my is or is not prime result

Comment: @user3520570 I gave you one line of code. What *exactly* did you change? Because changing the one line of code made your program work here.

Comment: @elliotfrisch I just changed that one line:    public static void main (String [] args){
  //prompt user to input a number

  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "); 
  // change string to int
         int number = Integer.parseInt(input); 

     //display message to user of their results
         BigInteger num = new BigInteger(input); 
         
          
         String output = num + " is" 
              + (IsPrime(num) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number.";

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, output);

Comment: @user3520570 I edited to include the entire code I have for main (I made no changes to `IsPrime`); and I added screen shots of the message(s) I get... one for the input, and one for 4 and one for 5.

Comment: I just realized I had unnecessary code under my boolean that was preventing it to run properly...Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you simply was wrong in the main code; try with this one;

```
public static void main (String [] args){
        //prompt user to input a number

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "); 
        // change string to int
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input); 

        //display message to user of their results
        BigInteger num = new BigInteger(input); 

        String output = number + " is" + (IsPrime(num) ? " " : " not ") + "a prime number: " + number;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, output);
    }
```

Angelo